# String is not displayed by the Web Console because of size

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using `JSON.stringify(myString)` in Mozilla Firefox to convert a JavaScript object to a JSON string.

This function is working very well, but `myString` is very large, and I have got an exception in Developer's Console:

> The string you are trying to view is too long to be displayed by the
>   Web Console.

And I can't fully copy json string.

I was trying to output this string in alert, but it has limit too.
If there is any work-around how to solve it ?

Comment: Just curious: `console.log(myString.length)` shows what?

Comment: If it's just to copy, create a div and do innerHTML = myString.

Comment: Why do you want to copy/log the string?

Comment: @FelixKling Why does it matter why he wants to copy the string?

Comment: @Amy: Because there might be a completely different solution to the actual problem they are trying to solve.

Comment: `copy(JSON.stringify(...))` stores the result of `JSON.stringify()` in the clipboard

Comment: @Guedes notepad++ shows length: 4790062

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firefox und Chrome provide some helpers available in the console.
One of these helpers is `copy()`

Firefox:
[`copy(object)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers#copy)
New in Firefox 38. Copy the argument to the clipboard. If the argument is a string, it's copied as-is. If the argument is a DOM node, its outerHTML is copied. Otherwise, JSON.stringify will be called on the argument, and the result will be copied to the clipboard.

Chrome:
[`copy(object)`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#copyobject)
copies a string representation of the specified object to the clipboard.

For Firefox it would be:

```
copy(yourObject)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could log it to localStorage:

```
 localStorage.setItem('JSON String', JSON.stringify(yourObject));
```

Comment: I'm new guy in javascript, I'm trying to do it, but : `[Exception... "Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: debugger eval code :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 1"  data: no]`

Comment: Maybe `String()` instead of `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @VLeonovs This typically means what it says -- that your attempt to access something can't be accomplished because that something is still in use somewhere else. You could try to set the `stringify` result in a variable first and then set it in localStorage after that completes.

Comment: @Guedes JSON doesn't have a `string()` method.

Comment: @Guedes That would just return `[Object object]`.